# Fade in elements on hover of their parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to Know how i can make array  in java script from css class and html class

Here is my HTML:

```
<li> 
    <a href="list2.html" class="img-list0">     
        <div class="list_City0">
            <img src="images/03.jpg" height="200"/>
            <h5 class="text-center">Alexandria</h5>
            <p class="text-center">Is very nice city. </p>
        </div> List page 1
    </a>
</li>
<!-- HERER MY ADD PLEASE DONT FORGET ----->
<li> <a href="list2.html" class="img-list1"> 
    <div class="list_City1">
        <img src="images/08.jpg" height="200"/>
        <h5 class="text-center">Cairo</h5>
        <p class="text-center">Is very nice city. </p>      
    </div>List page 2</a>
</li>
```

and my CSS:

```
.list_City0, .list_City1,.list_City9{
     background-size:cover;
     position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
     z-index:9999;
     display:none; 
     margin-left:220px;
     top:30px;
     box-shadow:4px 4px 5px #888;
     overflow:hidden;
     border-radius:10px;
}
```

i write in java script this because i dont like to write more onne line to do this

```
   var htmlarraycity=[$(".img-list0"),$(".img-list1"),$(".img-list9")];
        var cssarraycity=  [$(".list_City0"),$(".list_City1"),$(".list_City9")];

    for(i=0;htmlarraycity[i].length;i++){


            (htmlarraycity[i]).hover(function(){
        (cssarraycity[i]).fadeIn(1000);     

    });

       (htmlarraycity[i]).mouseleave(function(){
       (cssarraycity[i]).hide();

   });
```

Comment: and what is your question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [jQuery's "starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), you can bind to the hover event of all `.img-list*` elements without having to store each object in an array. Likewise, you can show/hide the nested `.list_City*` element as well. Finally, rather than using `fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()`, jQuery has a function called `fadeToggle()` that takes care of this logic for you.

**Snippet:**

```js
// starts with selector
$('*[class^="img-list"]').hover(function() {

  $(this).children('*[class^="list_City"]').fadeToggle(1000);

});
```

```css
.list_City0,
.list_City1,
.list_City9 {
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 220px;
  top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #888;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="list2.html" class="img-list0">
    <div class="list_City0">
      <img src="images/03.jpg" height="200" />
      <h5 class="text-center">Alexandria</h5>
      <p class="text-center">Is very nice city.</p>
    </div>List page 1
  </a>
</li>
<!-- HERER MY ADD PLEASE DONT FORGET ----->
<li>
  <a href="list2.html" class="img-list1">
    <div class="list_City1">
      <img src="images/08.jpg" height="200" />
      <h5 class="text-center">Cairo</h5>
      <p class="text-center">Is very nice city.</p>
    </div>List page 2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I would be careful about using the startwith selector as it appears that the OP is only selecting _specific_ classes, not all of them, ie 0, 1, and 9.

Comment: @Andy - honestly, I think the OP just wants to toggle a specific `div` when a specific `a` is hovered and doesn't understand that you don't need to have a different class name to achieve this. That was my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure all you need to do is the following - no need for arrays or loops:

```
var hoverlist = '.img-list0, .img-list1, .img-list9';
var showlist = '.list_City0, .list_City1, .list_City9';

$(hoverlist).hover(function () {
  $(showlist).fadeIn(1000);
},function () {
  $(showlist).hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/498zcvu6/20/)

Comment: Don't know why you got a negative vote, perfectly legitimate answer. I would however, just combine the two functions into one (hover has a callback for when you un-hover too). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/498zcvu6/18/).

Comment: Thanks Jamie. Not sure why I got a downvote either.

Comment: I should down-vote you for calling me James lol

Comment: @JamieBarker Woah, what's wrong with the name James?!  Also, this answer doesn't match the question (though there isn't really a clear question).  The title clearly implies a child-parent relationship.  This answer just shows and hides all of the elements.  I believe the implication is that only the related element (child) should show, not all of them.

Comment: +1 to offset the downvote. I think the OP wants just *the* city associated with the link to appear - not all of the cities. (could be wrong) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/498zcvu6/25/).

Comment: @JamesMontagne, Well, if you look at the code the OP wrote he's clearly looping over an array of classes and specifically switching off corroborating classes. I was just showing how his code could be cleaned up. You maybe right that the OP wants a one to one relationship, but I don't think you can tell that from the question. That title was edited by someone else btw who might not have understood what the OP wanted.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Well I took from it that the OP wanted their JS simplified so they weren't creating arrays and this does that. My problem with the name James is that a lot of people think that everyone called Jamie is actually a James!

Comment: @Andy Did not see the title edit.  This question is just junk and that title edit does seem a bit of a leap.

Comment: @JamieBarker I was just kidding.  I get the opposite at times and have to explain that Jamie is its own name, so I feel your pain!